# Issue calling isAvailable method @ionic-native/email-composer

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

**Current behavior:**
I have installed the email composer components as per the ionic documentation and the isAvailable function is not available.  I have read various documents regarding this subject but cannot find any way to get the method to work.

The rest of the plugin works perfectly when sending emails on my Android device so the plugin is definitely installed and working.

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: EmailComposer.getPlugin(...).isAvailable is not a function
```

**Expected behavior:**
I would expect the isAvailable method to return true or false.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. $ ionic start myApp blank
2. $ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-email-composer
3. $ npm install @ionic-native/email-composer

**Related code:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { EmailComposer } from '@ionic-native/email-composer/ngx';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['home.page.scss']
})
export class HomePage {
    constructor(private emailComposer: EmailComposer) {}

    public canEmail: boolean = false;

    ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.emailComposer.isAvailable().then((available: boolean) => {
            if (available) {
                this.canEmail = true;
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

**Other information:**

```
Ionic:                                                                                                               

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.2 (C:\Users\andy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)                      
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.3                                                             
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3                                                                           
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3                                                                             
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3                                                                             
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0                                                                             

Cordova:                                                                                                             

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)                                                                     
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0                                                                                 
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 5 other plugins)

Utility:                                                                                                             

   cordova-res : not installed                                                                                       
   native-run  : 0.2.8                                                                                               

System:                                                                                                              

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (c:\Android\Sdk)                                                                       
   NodeJS            : v10.15.2 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)                                                   
   npm               : 6.4.1                                                                                         
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Comment: Seems, the plugin is not installed. Did you add the plugin like, `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-email-composer`

Comment: Yes I did, I followed the instructions on the Ionic website and the module has been installed into the ```node_modules``` folder and if I bypass this call to isAvailable then the send email GMail form is initiated as one would expect.

Comment: Reading the plugin's repo, I see [`isAvailable` is replaced with `hasClient` and `hasAccount`](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer/commit/9f19ee5a8f27b18fce861f3412601dc84bf2f2e5)

Comment: Unfortunately those functions are not supported via the ```@ionic-native/email-composer``` module :/

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it helps anybody else out there.

After a few days of investigation I have come to the conclusion that the `cordova-plugin-email-composer` is out of line with the Ionic native library.  I have attempted to resolve the issue myself and my `@ionic-native` fork is available here [@ionic-native](https://github.com/ChelloApps/ionic-native) the specific file I have changed is located here `src\@ionic-native\plugins\email-composer.index.ts`.

I have created a pull request in the main ionic-native repository but its my first attempt of any kind contributing to a project like this so not sure on the outcome!

Comment: Thank you for this! I tried rolling back to cordova-plugin-email-composer@0.8.15 (last with isAvailable method) to allow use of @ionic-native/email-composer@4.2.0 .... but couldn't get it to work.

For anyone else looking for some help:
Copy @ionic-native\plugins\email-composer\index.ts from this fork and add it to your project - be sure to add it as a provider in app.module.ts. Update any .isAvailable() calls in your code to use .hasAccount(). Remove @ionic-native/email-composer your app. Remove the node_modules, plugins, and platform directories and reinstall node modules and platforms.

Comment: no worries, Ionic seem less than keen to allow the community to help with fixes like this they seem more interested in trying to sell there $5,000 per app enterprise licenses instead LOL!